# Can't get Mouse down event on a color to trigger

Tags: python, colors, pygame, mouseevent

I am creating an Avoider Game for a school project, and I came across a strange error where the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event won't trigger when the cursor clicks on green, (The "win color") even though an almost identical version of the same code **does** work, but with a different color.

My current code for the color-events are:

```
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    color_at_cursor = screen.get_at(pos)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and color_at_cursor == (0, 0, 255, 255):
        print("Game Start")
        start_clicked = True
    if start_clicked and color_at_cursor == (0, 228, 255, 255):
        died = True
    if died:
        screen.blit(ded, ded_rect)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            is_alive = False

  if start_clicked and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and color_at_cursor == (0, 255, 0, 255):
      screen.blit(win_screen, win_rect)
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          is_alive = False
```

where the first 3 if statements check if the blue start button was clicked, and if the cursor touches the cyan/light blue death color. These statements work as they are supposed to, but the final statement, which uses almost the exact same concept, doesn't work. When clicking on green, nothing happens. I came to the conclusion that the reason it doesn't work is because the green in question is located on a separate object than the background. But that was still strange because the second IF Statement above didn't result in immediate death when the cursor hovered over the platform, (which is colored differently than the background's cyan death color)

Anyways, I attempted to write code that could detect a mouse click event, on a certain color, on top of an object. As seen below:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and start_clicked:
    x, y = event.pos
    if platform1.get_rect().collidepoint(x,y) and platform1.get_at((x, y)) == (0, 255, 0, 255):
        print("win button clicked")
        screen.blit(win_screen, win_rect)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            is_alive = False
```

And this still resulted in nothing happening. Does anyone know why I am running into this problem, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you print out the color at the cursor on every step?  `print(platform1.get_at((x, y)))` Does it match the desired color?

Comment: You could also store the colors in global constants like WIN_COLOR, WALL_COLOR and so on, so that you only need to change it in one place.

Comment: could you check your indentation? The last `if` in your first snippet is less indented. Is like this in your code too? If so, where does the first block start?

Comment: In your second snippet... what are `platform1`, `win_screen` and `win_rect`?

Comment: @Valentino the indentation in the actual code is good, pasting into the website might have made it look weird. platform1 is the part that the user is supposed to keep the mouse on top of, basically it's an image that sits on top of the background (since I have the platform spinning in the game itself). win_screen is the .png file that *should* display when the green is clicked on, and win_rect is that .png file but as a rectangle so that it can show up properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second snippet, I'm not 100% sure what `platform1` is, but let me guess it is a Surface filled with green color.

If this is the case, the error is likely the offset of the coordinates. Let me illustrate this with the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is a simplified version of your second snippet:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

platform1 = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
platform1.fill((0, 255, 0))
screen.blit(platform1, (300, 300))
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            if platform1.get_rect().collidepoint(x,y) and platform1.get_at((x, y)) == (0, 255, 0):
                print("win button clicked")
```

Now this creates a green square in the middle of the screen, but when you click on  it, `"win button clicked"` is not printed (reproducing the error you describe).

The reason is that `event.pos` returns the coordinates of the mouse in the screen coordinate system: i.e. the position `(0, 0)` is the top left corner of the screen window.
However the rectangle you get from `platform1.get_rect()` does not know where the rectangle is actually drawn, so it's origin it is assumed to be `(0, 0)` instead of whatever it is (`(300, 300)` in this case). So you have an error when detecting the point collision.

If you replace the last `if` block with:

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        x, y = event.pos
        x -= 300
        y -= 300
        if platform1.get_rect().collidepoint(x,y) and platform1.get_at((x, y)) == (0, 255, 0):
            print("win button clicked")
```

It works as expected, because we accounted for the offset of `(300, 300)`.

This illustrates the problem, but of course is not a good way to solve it, because  the offset is hardcoded and will not be the same for all the objects. The best way to face this kind of situation is to use [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprites) instead of merely Surfaces, which can be used to track in a consistent way also the position of the object in the screen.

Comment: I added a variable that gets set to true when the green is clicked, and a separate if statement that displays the win screen when that variable is true, and it finally worked. I also made the win circle a sprite like you said, and I don't know if that actually affected the outcome, but at least it works now.